# Speed of a rocket at instant

Tags: calculus

At a distance of 12,000 feet from the launch site, a spectator is observing a rocket
being launched vertically. What is the speed of the rocket at the instant when the
distance of the rocket from the spectator is 13,000 feet and is increasing at the rate
of 480 ft/sec?

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ be the position of the observer, and let $P$ be the launch point. Let $Q=Q(t)$ be the position of the rocket at time $t$, and let $y=y(t)=PQ$ be the height of the rocket at time $t$. We want to find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ at a certain instant $t$ when the distance from $O$ to the observer is $13000$.

Draw the obvious right-angled triangle $OPQ$.  Let $h$ be the length of the hypotenuse $OQ$. By the Pythagorean Theorem, we have
$$h^2=12000^2+y^2.$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$. We get 
$$2h\frac{dh}{dt}=2y\frac{dy}{dt}.\tag{1}$$
At the instant when $h=13000$, we have $\frac{dh}{dt}=480$ and $y=\sqrt{13000^2-12000^2}$. Substitute in (1) to find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ at that instant.